# Do I need to stub EVERYTHING in this method in order to pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, minitest

I am generally new to mocha and I hate using this gem but I need to use it in order to pass a test that I am constructing. What is giving me problems is what I'm supposed to mock and how I am supposed to mock it. To illustrate my point, Here is an example of a method that I am testing:

```
 def statistics_of_last_24_hrs
    stats = ses.statistics.find_all { |s| s[:sent].between?(Time.now.utc - 24.hours, Time.now.utc) }
    sent_last_24_hrs = ses.quotas[:sent_last_24_hours].to_f
    no_of_bounces = stats.inject(0.0) { |a, e| a + e[:bounces] }
    no_of_complaints = stats.inject(0.0) { |a, e| a + e[:complaints] }
    bounce_rate = sent_last_24_hrs.zero? ? 0.0 : (no_of_bounces / sent_last_24_hrs) * 100
    complaint_rate = sent_last_24_hrs.zero? ? 0.0 : (no_of_complaints / sent_last_24_hrs) * 100
    fail(Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError, 'Bounce Rate exceeded 5%') if bounce_rate >= 5.0 
    fail(Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError, 'Complant Rate exceeded .1%')if complaint_rate >= 0.1 
  end
```

Basically what this code is doing is getting some statistics from an Amazon api call and then calculating them to determine if my bounce/complaint rate has exceeded the limit. The limit is 5% and 0.1% respectively.

Basically for my test all I really need to do is to stub the variables `bounce_rate` and `complaint_rate` in order to test whether the right exception is thrown.

This is where I am getting stuck. Here is a barebones test that I would ideally write:

```
it 'should raise SimpleEmailServieLimitError if bounce rate is above 5%' do
  assert_raise Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError do
     Reverification::Process.statistics_of_last_24_hrs
  end
end
```

How can I stub the `bounce_rate` and then the `complaint_rate`. I've done some searching around and came to the conclusion that there isn't a way to stub variables. I also looked at this link [List of Mocha Methods](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/method_list.html)Which confirms my findings.

Is there a way I can just write a test like this:

```
 it 'should raise SimpleEmailServieLimitError if bounce rate is above 5%' do
  stubs(:bounce_rate).returns(true)
  assert_raise Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError do
     Reverification::Process.statistics_of_last_24_hrs
  end
end
```

Or do I have to stub every method call in this method so that the test will look something like this:

```
it 'should raise SimpleEmailServieLimitError if bounce rate is above 5%' do
  sent_last_24_hrs = 20
  over_bounce_limit = MOCK::AWS::SimpleEmailService.over_bounce_limit
  AWS::SimpleEmailService.any_instance.stubs(:statistics).returns(stub(find_all: over_bounce_limit))
  AWS::SimpleEmailService.any_instance.stubs(:quotas).returns(stub(sent_last_24_hours: sent_last_24_hrs))
  etc. etc. etc...........
  assert_raise Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError do
     Reverification::Process.statistics_of_last_24_hrs
  end
end
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if there was a way to stub local variables, that feature would produce tests that are very hard to maintain because you'd not be able to refactor your code without changing tests.

Nested stubs are design smell too - your tests will know about too much implementation details and will become unmaintainable.

The same can be said for stubbing third-party code as any changes to the third-party library will allow your tests to pass while the code does not work.

It is a lot better to create your own wrapper around AWS SimpleEmailService - gateway. You'd implement it to have a very narrow stable interface like

```
class BounceStatistics
  def no_of_bounces
  def no_of_complaints
  def sent_last_24_hrs
end
```

Since this interface is your own and it is stable, you can safely stub it and provide alternative implementation for your tests:

```
assert_raise Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError do
  Reverification::Process.statistics_of_last_24_hrs(
    stub(no_of_bounces: 2, no_of_complaints: 3, sent_last_24_hrs: 5))
end
```

alternatively you may implement it as

```
BounceStatistics.any_instance.stubs(:no_of_bounces).returns(2)
BounceStatistics.any_instance.stubs(:no_of_complaints).returns(3)
BounceStatistics.any_instance.stubs(:sent_last_24_hrs).returns(5)

assert_raise Reverification::SimpleEmailServiceLimitError do
  Reverification::Process.statistics_of_last_24_hrs
end
```

However passing dependencies explicitly allows you to have more maintainable code and simpler tests.

Comment: Thanks windock. I didn't even think of this approach. Much appreciated.